# In which sense does Kuhn acknowledge the importance of metaphors in science?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, kuhn

Kuhn, in *Metaphors and Through* [1993], claims:

> “Metaphors play an essential role in establishing links between
>   scientific language and the world. Those links are not, however, given
>   once and for all. Theory change, in particular, is accompanied by a
>   change in some of the relevant metaphors and in the corresponding
>   parts of the network of similarities through which terms attach to
>   nature.”

Given that exemplars correspond to images of something concrete, and let scientists see similarities between similar problems, can examplars be seen as metaphors as well?

Which is the main sense of "metaphor in science" in Kuhn's philosophy?

Comment: Is the reference *Metaphors and Through* correct?

Comment: @FrankHubeny - **NO**. It is *Metaphor in Science*, published into Andrew Ortony (editor), [*Metaphor and Thought*](https://books.google.it/books?id=QiJRvuXA_VcC&pg=PA533) (Cambridge UP, 1993) and reprinted as Ch.8 of  Thomas Kuhn, The Road since Structure : Philosophical Essays 1970-1993 (The University of Chicago Press, 2000).

Comment: See [Metaphor](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/metaphor/#FourTrad) for the context of Kuhn's paper : [Max Balck's theory](https://web.stanford.edu/~eckert/PDF/Black1954.pdf) of the way metaphor works.

Comment: Not clear... [exemplars](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/thomas-kuhn/#3) in Kuhn's *SSR* are books: Ptolemy's *Almagest*, Lavoisier's *Traité élémentaire de chimie*, and Newton's *Principia Mathematica* and *Opticks*.

Comment: this almost reads like an apologia of Jordan Peterson